# read iCloud settings for Reminders

Tags: ios, settings, icloud, preferences, reminders

Is there a way to know if Reminders is synced with iCloud programmatically?

In the settings of the device, iCloud, the user can enable/disable iCloud sync for several apps (Mail, Contacts, Calendars...). My App will behave differently if iCloud is enabled for Reminders, but I can't find a way to check this setting.

Does anyone know? Thank you for your help!

Comment: Have you found the solution for this? if yes please let me know

Comment: no solution yet, but maybe there's hope with the ios8 cloudkit.